# Javascript algorithm - section list of messages by date

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, optimization, ecmascript-6

### INTRODUCTION

I am fetching messages from my database (using bidirectional pagination (recent messages at the bottom, old messages at the top), so every time I fetch 15 messages, I section them into their respective date group.

I'm a bit stuck since the algorithm is somewhat complex if you want to get a good performance...

### CODE

Here is my current code:

```
export default class MessagesDatesSectioner {
  constructor(
    dateOptions = {
      weekday: "short",
      year: "numeric",
      month: "short",
      day: "numeric",
    }
  ) {
    this.dateOptions = dateOptions;
    this.sections = [];
    this.sectionsRef = new Map();
  }

  /**
  * Group a list of messages by date, generating a list of sections
  * which contains a title (the messages day as string), and an array
  * of data that contains all the messages.
  *
  * @param {list of objects}     messages     [{ date, text }, ...].
  */
  sectionizeMessagesByDate(messages) {
    let sections = messages.reduce((sections, message) => {
      const key =
        message.date
          .toDate?.()
          .toLocaleDateString(undefined, this.dateOptions) ||
        message.date.toLocaleDateString(undefined, this.dateOptions);

      if (!sections[key]) {
        sections[key] = [];
      }

      sections[key].push(message);

      return sections;
    }, {});

    sections = Object.keys(sections).map((key) => ({
      title: key,
      data: sections[key],
    }));

    // Merge the resulted sections with the existed ones
    this.mergeNewMessagesSections(sections);
  }

  /**
  * Get a list of new sections (or groups of messages), and merge them
  * with the existing sections.
  *
  * @param {list of objects}     newMessagesSections     [{ title: "Monday", data: [{date, text}, ...], }, ...].
  */
  mergeNewMessagesSections(newMessagesSections) {
    for (const { title, data } of newMessagesSections) {
      if (!this.sectionsRef.has(title)) {
        this.sectionsRef.set(title, this.sections.length);
        this.sections.push({ title, data: [] });
      }

      this.sections[this.sectionsRef.get(title)].data.push(...data);
    }
  }

  deleteMessage(message) {
    // TODO
  }
  
  // Return a copy of the sections list
  getSections() {
    return [...this.sections];
  }
}
```

### PROBLEM

My problem comes when adding data to those structures. As I am using a bidirectional pagination, the new messages might have an earlier or later date than the previously-sectioned messages.

For example:

```
  1- Call sectionizeMessagesByDate() with the following messages
          [
             { date: new Date("10/31/2000 00:00:01"), text: "Hello" },
             { date: new Date("10/31/2001 00:00:02"), text: "World" },
          ] // Note: All messages are sorted by date in the given array by default (Do not care about it)

  2- When merging, as there is no data in the sections list, it will generate the following:
          [
              {
                title: "10/31/2000",
                data: [ { date: new Date("10/31/2000 00:00:01"), text: "Hello" } ]  
              },
              {
                title: "10/31/2001", // Other year (different date)
                data: [ { date: new Date("10/31/2000 00:00:02"), text: "Hello" } ]  
              }
          ]
```

As you can see, new sections are added to the tail of the current sections list when merging...

So, if the class generates a new section which date is "10/31/1999", it will be added to the bottom, not preserving a date order.

Any ideas how to implement the ordering (by dates) between sections and sections messages (in the data array) preserving a good performance?

Note: The map 'sectionsRef' has the title of the section as key, and it index in the sections list as value, just to achieve a O(1) complexity order when inserting messages into existing sections.

Comment: How many items are you typically sorting?

Comment: @jarmod This algorithm is for a chat screen (depends on the user scroll). On each scroll end reached (or top reached, because of the bidirection), the user gets 15 new messages (ordered by date) from the database. These 15 items are directly passed to this class (messagesDatesSectioner.sectionizeMessagesByDate(listOfMessages)).

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can think

(Not implemented, I have written the pseudocode)

There are a lot of suppositions, but I suppose you are talking about the typical WhatsApp chat.

For ordering both sections and messages, you will have to also add a "firstMessageDate" field (in the pseudo called "date") which has to be a JS Date Object, because you cannot build them like follows:

```
  const date = new Date("Monday"); // Invalid date
```

Here is my spaghetti algorithm:

```
  mergeNewMessagesSections(newMessagesSections) {
    for (const { title, data } of newMessagesSections) {
      // If the section doesnt exist...
      if (!this.sectionsRef.has(title)) {
        // 1. Insert the section at the head or at the tail of the existing sections list?
        // if (section.date > sections[0].date)
        //       insert the older section at the head of the existing sections list
        //       Also, reorder (recalculate) the sectionsRef indices and add it to the head of the map
        // else
        //       insert the newer section at the tail of the existing sections list
        //       No map reordering required, just insert the section at the end of the refs map
        //
        //
        //
        // Note:
        //     In the typical chat screens, the top section of messages is always older than the middle section of messages
        //     In the other hand, the bottom section of messages is always newer then the middle ones.

        this.sections.push({ title, data: [] });
        this.sectionsRef.set(title, this.sections.length);
      }

      // 2. Insert the messages at the head or at the tail of the existing section?
      // if (section.date >= sections[this.sectionsRef.get(title)].data[0])
      //       insert the old messages at the head of the section
      // else
      //       insert the most fresh messages at the tail of the section
      //
      //
      //  Note: (as happen with sections)
      //      In chat screens, the top messages are always older than the middle messages.
      //      In the other hand, the bottom messages are always newer than the middle ones.
      //

      this.sections[this.sectionsRef.get(title)].data.push(...data);
    }
  }
```